# Bone rotation does not match Model rotation

Tags: modeling, bones

can someone tell me how to fix my bone rotations being all skrewed up?
preferably with pictures?

as you can see here his model hip is all desynced with the bone hip
[image]

Comment: you need to correct the parentage, either in Weight Paint mode, or in Edit mode with the Vertex Groups list where you can assign the vertex to the group you want.

Comment: Hard to tell with so little infowes, I think you should upload your file.

Comment: here is the link to the link :P https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jCtVwGrpB8jsSrX-HJOWVn4WSeDpMIW7